# How to add route to the same subnet via two interfaces simultaneously?

Tags: linux, networking, ip, routing, iproute2

I am currently using GNU/Linux
Have the following routing table:

```
default via 192.168.1.1 dev eno1  proto static  metric 100 
10.0.0.0/8 dev enp1s0  scope link linkdown 
169.254.0.0/16 dev virbr0  scope link  metric 1000 linkdown 
192.168.1.0/24 dev eno1  proto kernel  scope link  src 192.168.1.2  metric 100 
192.168.122.0/24 dev virbr0  proto kernel  scope link  src 192.168.122.1 linkdown
```

I use NIC with eno1 to connect to the internet via gateway on subnet `192.168.1.0/24`

I use NIC with enp1s0 to act as a NAT gateway(`10.0.0.1`) for my internal subnet(`10.0.0.0/8`)
Now I want to add(learning purposes) route to `10.0.0.0/8` subnet via my external(eno1) interface:

```
# Added route via eno1, resulting in routing table shown above
ip route add 10.0.0.0/8 dev enp1s0
# When I add route via enp1s0, command causes error
ip route add 10.0.0.0/8 dev eno1
RTNETLINK answers: File exists
```

Could you show please how to solve this problem? Thanks.

Comment: Could you be more elaborate? Meaningful rationale would be highly appreciated.

Comment: How does the kernel decide where the packets go to? Your question is a bit similar to "why can't have 2 same named file in one directory?".

Comment: @Ipor, For example, to make kind of balancing, multipath routing(doesn't know precisely appropriate word), by adding some kind of weight to the route, no?

Comment: @Ipor, of course, I just offer you possibility to earn some rep by writing good answer) We are here to help you in good deeds.